# EF Core MySQL - LINQ statements created inefficient query

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework-core

I have an object called inventory which is of type IQueryable. When i use linq to run inventory.Count(), the following SQL is produced (i used entity framework logger to see the actual query being produced):

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM Inventory
```

I have another linq statement that takes that same inventory object and runs the following command on it:

```
inventory.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct().Count();
```

And this one produces this SQL query:

```
SELECT Id, name, quantity, cost
FROM Inventory
```

It doesn't use SQL count syntax. Why? If the first linq statement creates creates an optimized sql query, why does this one create an inefficient one?

Comment: Are you sure, this doesn't make a lot of sense really. is this SQL server? `.Distinct()` should really run on the server side, assuming you arent sending it through some ghastly repository

Comment: it's a mysql database. I am concerned with how linq is being transformed into sql. The way it's currently working is super inefficient, doing the count and distinct on server side.

Comment: Sounds like the mysql EF provider is doing funky things, 99.999 percent sure sql server wouldn't pull back the table to do a distinct

Comment: What EF Core version are you on?

Comment: I'm using MySql.Data.Entityframework 8.0.16

Comment: I meant the *EF Core* version. Because the SQL translation is mainly controlled by the EF Core infrastructure, and is improved over the EF Core releases. Looks like your version is using client evaluation, while I believe the latest EF Core 2 should be able to translate it to the expected optimal SQL.

Comment: Ivan -- i guess im not understanding. I'm using MySql.Data.Entityframework. Do I also need to reference the core entity framework library? Isn't that already referenced by the MySql.Data.Entityframework library? I can't control what references it is using..